# Security Exception: Permission denial for DEVICE_POWER

Tags: android, permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to write a simple android app that switches off my phone screen. When I am runnning this app I get Security Exception: Permission denial app requires android.permission.DEVICE_POWER. I know that this is a protected permission but my phone is rooted. What do I specify that I can use this permission? I have already tried declaring DEVICE_ADMIN permssion along with the DEVICE_POWER permission but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rooting potentially lets you circumvent or modify the android security model, but it doesn't necessarily mean you get special privileges for an android API which enforces it.  You cannot ordinarily run an application itself as root, while code in a helper executable which you could start as root will have substantial difficulty interacting with the Android APIs.

What you are trying to do may really not be a very good idea.  But if you really want to do it, you would need to either install your own build of Android so that you have a (self generated) key matching that which you used to sign the platform, which you can then use to sign your application, or else try to install your application on the system partition.

Comment: I agree, can you give some more info on signing? Signing like that though restricts the application to that particular build right? And if I install to system partition as it is (without any changes) will it work or should some changes be made to run in system ?

Comment: I installed the aplication in my system partition still i get E/AndroidRuntime( 1226): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10008 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.
 Is there no way without custom android build to do this?

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is turn the screen off, then why don't you use the [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)? According to the documentation, the [goToSleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29) function will force the device to go to sleep.

Comment: I am using power managers go to sleep. Using that is throwing me security exception